# ng-attr interpolation not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, interpolation

I'm trying to generate tabs that optionally have an attribute called 'if-permission-keep' if a property 'permissions' is set in a data structure that's being iterated over to create the tabs. Here is what the data structure looks like:

```
  $scope.tabs = [
    {heading: "Details", 
     route:"facilities-view.details"
    },
    {heading: "Devices",
     route:"facilities-view.devices",
     style:"fas fa-fw fa-lg fa-mobile",
     permissions:"'mobile_device_manage'"
    },...
 ];
```

This is the html for the tabs with AngularJS directives:

```
<uib-tab ng-repeat="t in tabs" index="t.route" select="showTab(t.route)"
         ng-attr-if-permission-keep = "t.permissions">
```

My understanding of how ng-attr worked is if the expression, in this case "t.permissions", is undefined then the attribute is not added to the element. Otherwise, the attribute is added with the value of the expression. But it seems as if even when the expression evaluates to undefined, it adds the attribute with the value of defined. Is there something different about using ng-attr within an ng-repeated element?

Answer (score 0):

The expression needs to be interpolated:

```
<uib-tab ng-repeat="t in tabs" index="t.route" select="showTab(t.route)"
         ng-attr-if-permission-keep = "{{t.permissions}}">
```

See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Interpolation - `ngAttr` for binding to arbitrary attributes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes).

Comment: I initially tried it with the double braces around the expression, as per the documentation, but I got the following error: "Token '{' invalid key at column 2". I assumed I was getting that error because the $interpolate method parsed it differently within the ng-repeat scope. Notice the expressions for the other ng directives do not use the double braces, and those work.